# Django: Optimization using forms .has_changed in save method

Tags: python, django

I just noticed that django forms has a method [.has_changed()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/api/#checking-which-form-data-has-changed) and I'm just wondering if it would be a good idea for optimization to use it by overriding the save method and checking if form has changed before hitting the db?

By doing this we would actually skip one unnecessary call to the db. What do you guys think about it?

Would look something like this:

```
def save(self, commit=False):
    property = super(PropertyPriceForm, self).save(commit=False)

    if self.is_valid():
        ...

        if commit and self.has_changed():
            property.save()

    return property
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a good idea and can reduce the database load. however, its important to evaluate the potential benefits of customizing forms in your specific case before implementing solutions.

While optimizing the database is important, it's essential to be cautious when introducing customization and increasing the code's complexity for that purpose. sometimes the cost you incur in terms of increased complexity may not explain the gains from optimizing a single query.